# Смена отдельных тайлов в процессе игры в unity 2d

Tags: unity3d, tilemap

По задумке игры, персонаж при соприкосновении с тайлом должен менять этот тайл на другой, но просто делать тайлмап под тайлмапом и потом частично скрывать один, чтобы показался другой слишком сложно особенно когда видов тайлов больше 10 штук.